# has_post_format() vs. get_post_format()

Tags: post-formats

I just stepped into the concept of **post formats** and was wondering why there are two out of 3 functions from the post format "API" offer absolutely the same functionality. Consider the following two concepts (A vs. B):

```
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while ( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();

        // A) has_post_format
        if ( has_post_format('format') )
        {
            the_excerpt(); // some special formating
        }

        // VERSUS:

        // B) 
        if ( get_post_format( $GLOBALS['post']->ID ) == 'format' )
        {
            the_excerpt(); // some special formating
        }

    } // endwhile;
} // endif;
```

Could someone please explain me why there are those two functions instead only ex. `get_post_format`? If you could offer me some examples of situations where the one isn't capable of something the other function can do, I'd be special happy and +1 it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Edit

`has_post_format()` requires a string, `$format`, as the first parameter; which means that it can only be used to test for explicit post-format types:

```
if ( has_post_format( $format ) {
    // Current post has the $format post format;
    // do something
}
```

To determine if a post has *any* post format, use `get_post_format()`, which will return `false` if the current post does not have a post format assigned:

```
if ( false != get_post_format() ) {
    // Current post has a post format;
    // do something
}
```

Note that **"standard"** isn't an *actual* post-format, but is rather a *placeholder* term for posts that do not have a post format assigned. Internally, WordPress returns `false` rather than `post-format-standard`, so, to query for the "standard" post-format type, you would just use `if ( false == get_post_format() )`.

### Original

`has_post_format()` returns a BOOLEAN value, which is useful for conditionals, e.g.:

```
if ( ! has_post_format() ) {
     // I'm a standard-format post; do something
}
```

or

```
if ( has_post_format( array( 'gallery', 'image' ) ) {
     // I'm a gallery or image format post; do something
}
```

`get_post_format()` returns the string value of the current post format type, which is useful in several ways. One of the most powerful is to call different template part files based on post format, e.g.:

```
get_template_part( 'entry', get_post_format() )
```

Which will include, e.g. "entry-aside.php" for an aside format, or "entry.php" for a standard format.

Comment: The `get_template_part` is really smart!

Comment: Bennet - complete forgot to mark your A as solution. Btw: All As were upvoted :)

Comment: `if ( ! has_post_format() ) {}` returns a warning (as of 3.5-RC1 at least) since the 1st (required) argument is missing. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_format

Answer (score 4):

*The following part is not correct, I have [created a ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17320) to request this enhancement.*

<s>[`has_post_format()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-includes/post.php#L503) is more flexible because it builds upon [`has_term()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1190), which builds upon [`is_object_in_term()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2983). This means you can pass an array of post formats and it will return `true` if the posts has one of these formats.</s>

```
if ( has_post_format( array( 'aside', 'video' ) ) {
    // It's an aside or a video
}
```

The original specification ticket [already mentioned](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14746) both `get_post_format()` and `has_post_format()`, maybe because it builds upon the taxonomy system which also has both functions?

Comment: Oh, definitely, this further extends what you can do here by allowing you to check on specific formats in order to get your true/false answer back.

Comment: Makes me think if it would make sense to simply use the `is_object_in_term()` function instead.

Comment: @kaiser: Post formats are saved as "post-format-*" as the actual term, you would have to add this yourself. These specific functions are an abstraction, they hide the implementation so it can change in the future.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - i'm aware of builtin taxonomies and terms. Just thinking if this would give me more possibilities later on.

Comment: @Jan Fabry `has_post_format()` expects a **string** as first parameter. An array will fail.

Comment: @toscho: Darn, I knew I should have tested that instead of just glancing at the code. Then it is inconsistent with other `has_*` functions - I have [created a ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17320) for it.

Comment: @Jan Fabry That’s a very cool way to fix your answer. :)

Comment: @toscho: Must not lose those precious upvotes!

Answer (score 3):

Simple, has_post_format() returns a true/false (Boolean) value which is useful in IF statements, while get_post_format() returns the post format, if one exists, and probably NULL or false if one isn't there. Using Boolean values is a good clean way of making sure your conditions always behave the way you were expecting and the has_post_format() function allows for nice easy short conditions:

```
if ( has_post_format() ) {
  //yes we do
} else {
  //no we do not
}

if ( !has_post_format() ) {
  //no we do not
} else {
  //yes we do
}
```

Also, this just falls in line with other existing WordPress functionality. While your option B gets things done, it requires a bit more specialized knowledge than maybe the slightly above-average WordPress user is familiar with.

Comment: Reminds me of the `get_adjacent_post` and `next_post_link` stuff.