# How can I achieve something like has_post_format( 'standard' )?

Tags: conditional-tags, post-formats

In opposite to `get_post_format`, the conditional `has_post_format()` function returns a boolean value and should be the perfect function for a conditional check like:

```
if ( has_post_format( array( 'gallery', 'image' ) ) {
    // I'm a gallery or image format post; do something
}
```

(see this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14314/23011))

Unfortunately, `has_post_format()` is not sufficient to check for the *standard* post format. So how would I achieve something like:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'standard' ) {
    // I'm a standard format post
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [has\_post\_format() vs. get\_post\_format()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/has-post-format-vs-get-post-format)

Comment: Addressed in the linked answer, making this a *duplicate*.

Answer (score 3):

To do that, one needs to go back to `get_post_format()` as the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format#Returns) explains:

```
$format = get_post_format();
if ( false === $format )
    $format = 'standard';
```

So in order to check if a post is in standard format, I can use this shortcut:

```
if ( false == get_post_format() ) {
    // I'm a standard format post
}
/* or */
if ( ! get_post_format() ) {
    // I'm a standard format post
}
```

Or reverse the scheme to check if a post is just **not** in standard format:

```
if ( false !== get_post_format() ) {
    // I'm everything but a standard format post
}
/* or */
if ( get_post_format() ) {
    // I'm everything but a standard format post
}
```

Comment: Or simply use `if ( get_post_format() )` or `if ( ! get_post_format() )` ;)

Comment: @kaiser Totally, answer updated!